# how to pass NSManagedObjectContext around in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using .xibs and I want to use Core Data. The simplest answer is to define `@property` in AppDelegate.h. But I need to fill my model in xml-parser files and I want to fetch data in many controllers. So using `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] context]` there is so ugly.
Is there any good-looking solution?

Comment: Create a singleton `..DataManager` and have it control access to the data store.

Comment: Yes, i thought about it. If there is no any solution, i'll make singleton

Comment: Have also a look at the [Core Data Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html): *"... Nested contexts make it more important than ever that you adopt the “pass the baton” approach of accessing a context (by passing a context from one view controller to the next) rather than retrieving it directly from the application delegate."*

Answer (score 1):

Remember that every object that subclass `NSManagedObject` also have context.
Lets say you have (classic example) `Book` and `Author`. This is Entitis ofc. With relationship 1-n (one author  - multiple books).

I'm not aware of what you try to accomplished here, but in many of applications you have master-detail-more details - ... viewControllers. So back to example:

Lets say that your MainViewController is a `AuthorsViewController`. This is a tableView with authors. You want to tap on author and see what books he wrote. So in your `BooksViewController` you have one model property:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) Author *author;
```

You could set it in many different ways. Custom setter, pass from segue... nevermind. I'm sure this is pretty obvious.

What is great here that after you do this you already have a context in your `BooksViewController`. Every time you write:

`self.author.managedObjectContext` this will be the right context.

So when you have `navigationController` app you may create context in `AppDelegate` or in singleton class or in mainVC. You will only call it once, and then calling it from `NSManagedObject` that you will pass.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this great tutorial : [core data with a single shared uimanageddocument](http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html)